# GCP Vertex AI: Schedule a Pipeline ("create scheduled run" button missing)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scheduler, google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex-ai-pipeline

I was trying to schedule a Vertex AI pipeline from the UI instead of the SDK. I have previously scheduled another pipeline and it was running fine.

However, I realised the "Create Scheduled Run" button was missing in the UI.
[image]

After I changed my region, the button was there in that region. Can anyone clarify why this discrepancy?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the region in your first image, us-central1, it looks like there is a pipeline run that is scheduled, so the UI button that shows up with "you don't have any schedules in this project yet" isn't there. However, you can use the "Create Run" button at the top and then select "Recurring" instead of "One-off" in the Run schedule section[image]